# In eclipse, I have an error in a javascript file written a class with private fields

Tags: javascript, eclipse

Like an image bellow, I have an error in a javascript file wrriten a class with private fields in eclipse.
Is's no problem in the "class" words but there is a problem in the "#" words at private fields.
I can run this project with no error.
So it is the correct code.
Can I solve the problem?

[image: I]

Comment: Yes, it is a correct code, `#variabe` is not yet understood by eclipse, it is compiling for old version of ECMA Script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a correct code, `#variable` is not yet understood by eclipse, it is compiling for old version of ECMA Script

The warning appears due to asian characters you type inside the code, try to remove the asian language from the code and use plain english, then Eclipse will take it.

Comment: About which Eclipse JavaScript support are you talking, Eclipse JSDT or Eclipse Wild Web developer? Have you tested both?

Comment: simple eclipse project with `org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature` - as soon as you put `#` it will say `'}' expected` in the `Markers` -- eclipse `4.11.0`

Comment: So you talk about JSDT, but the current _Eclipse IDE for Web and JavaScript Developers_ is based on [Eclipse Wild Web developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper), not on JSDT anymore. And by the way, 4.11 is 4 releases behind.

Comment: I opened a javascript file with Wild Web Developer in eclipse, but I had the same error about a private field.
Maybe, this problem is not yet solved?

eclipse version
  Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers (includes Incubating components)
  Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0)
  Build id: 20201210-1552

Comment: please use, Enide Studio 2014 "tern-eclipse" project